# How can I find lakes?

Tags: terraria

Why aren't there any lakes to fish in? The only one I found is 1 block deep and is in the rain forest, where bats, slimes and piranhas could attack me at any moment.

This is what I've explored so far

[image]

How can I find proper lakes?

Comment: That doesn't look like a whole world at all.  Have you gone all the way to one end?

Comment: Not only is this not even close to being a full world, there's a small lake in plain sight at the far right of that picture.

Comment: I've noticed that you tend to write titles as x problem, need help - try using the title to explain more precisely what you want to know. You are likely to get better answers that way.

Comment: oh ok, guys im kind of sorry for wasting your time. and no, I haven't I cant get through the jungle with my current equipment.

Comment: @TerrariaGuy Don't worry, just try to explore the whole situation. Asking a question should be when all ideas and possibilities have been exhausted.

Comment: Wait until you build better armor and weapons. You can also refer to the Terraria Wiki: http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Terraria_Wiki for guides and buidlds

Answer (score 2):

Try going underground to get the material for a Bucket (Iron or lead bars). There will probably be an underground lake. You can use that bucket to move the water to the surface, or just fish in that same spot underground.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a lake you can make one. You can make a new world, find the Angler and keep doing quests to get the Bottomless Water Bucket. Or if you dont want all the work you can just get a  Bottomless Water Bucket with Hacks.